# AngularJS Image Gallery redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gallery

I am building an image gallery where users can upload there own images using AngularJS + Django. If a user clicks on an image, the website should redirect to a detail page where the image can be edited.

Currently I am able to show the detail view, but always starting with the first element.

```
function showImage(id)
    {
      $location.url('/'user'/'project'/detail');
    }
```

How can I redirect the user to the correct detail image without using another url parameter? (Or without showing the current image detail as a parameter)

Answer (score 0):

In your routes you set:

```
$routeProvider.when('/user/project/:id')
```

then now redirect with the function:

```
function(id) {
    $location.url('user/project/' + id );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manage more urls, you can use factories to store some application state https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers